# "Keeping a distance" vs "keeping my distance."

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Do both mean the same? Or there's a slight difference?

Example sentence:

> I got on the train, keeping **a/my** distance from Sumire (four people
>   away) then got off with her (twenty minutes later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping *my* distance implicitly defines the distance as whatever you are comfortable with, because it's *your* distance. It sugggests that you are successfully avoiding something or someone. There's an element of emotive language to it - because it's *your* distance, it's obviously meaningful to you.

Keeping *a* distance is non-quantitative, and such, sounds like it's missing something. I'd expect it to be used with something to quantify:

> ...keeping a short/reasonable/safe distance from Sumire...

or

> ...keeping a distance of four seats from Sumire...

I'd also say it's more factual than emotive, because you remove "ownership" of the distance.

At least, that's my own personal experience (Australian English). Someone might be able to help out with some actual references.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question. Is it correct to say: "I stood four people away from Sumire?"

Comment: Yep, that sounds fine to me, and is more concise than the original example.